# Posting Message to iframe using window.postMessage

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, firefox-addon

I am stuck at stupid problem. I am trying to develop a Firefox Extension in which I have a popup panel and in that panel, there is an iframe of a tasks.html File.

I want to postMessage to that iframe on click of a button in my web page(Say webpage interaction with the plugin) but its not working.

Here is the image to the Panel on how it looks.

[image: Panel]

This is the function, M using to send data to the iframe. The Post Function is called when the button in the webpage is clicked.

```
function Post() {
    var iframe = window.document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow;
    postMessageToWindow(iframe, "Hello");
}

function postMessageToWindow(win, message) {
    try {
        win.postMessage(message, '*');
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
         return false;
    }
}
```

and In that html page, I have

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var str_data = e.data;
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = str_data;
});
```

but nothing gets shown in the test DIV.

Please help me with it. Thanks.

Comment: Are the iframe and HTML doc on the same domain?

Comment: @PhilipBevan No Domain. Its in the Firefox Addon. `<iframe id="iframe" src="chrome://addon/content/sample.html" width="400px" and height="400px">` is in `sample.xul`. sample.xul and sample.html are in the same folder though.

Comment: its not a domain issue. where is that function Post() { ... } and function postMessageToWindow code?  you are running the window.addEventListener from the head of the iframe onload right?

Comment: @Noit The function Post is in overlay.js and no, I didn't make it an onload event. But I tried it, it wasnt working that way as well. M not sure though, if I scripted it right.

Comment: can you upload your code please ill take a , like a simplified addon test case

Comment: @Noit Sry, For the late reply, Here it is `https://app.box.com/s/hxnl6axnxbwcl5lh92g5`, I have edited my plugin a little (can not reveal all code you see, should work). Oh! and the button will appear in Gmail(when you open a mail) :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore my message about win.postMessage I didn't know that postMessage was a "native" function. It's cool helping you I learned something.

Anyways yes it would be nice if your code worked on first time. Thanks to some info from Blargh I found your problem.

Find `sample_button.appendChild(tasks_popup);` and remove that, why were you doing that? Right now its cloning the original object and adding it.

Another thing, why go through postMessage? Instead of postMessage you can simply do `tasks_iframe.contentDocument.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = 'why bother with postMessage, just do this? but i fixed postMessage for you too<br>';`

Another thing, the interval of 300ms works but its intensive and not the best solution. It will work for now though.

Do you have plans to upload this to addons.mozilla.org? They don't like setting innerHTML, if you plan to release there let me know and I'll show you how to do it without innerHTML.

Also your "Refresh" button in the panel in overlay.xul needs fixing to `document.getElementById('tasks-list').contentDocument.location.reload()`

Comment: Oh My God!!!!!!!! This is so stupid of me, the appendChild line was only for testing purposes, to see if the panel was opening or not. It had to be commented out!!!! (I read in some forum that we should do that, so I did). Also, I'll be glad to know On how we can add a button to gmail in a different way. Add me on skype (prateek.kathal). And again, that refresh button was only for testing... I didn't even click on it even once. But I think my way is fine, I read about that on  stackoverflow only. Thanks so much Noit. And Blargh, sorry for So much trouble. I should have properly checked this.

Comment: Will create a demo for you sometime soon on how to watch for gmail location changes. Please send me reminders in case I take a while. I don't mind multiple reminders at all. THe demo I make will help me as well.

Comment: And are you sure you want to use win.postMessage, if you just access tasks_iframe.contentDocument you can remove that even listener from tasks.html as well, saves 20 lines of code

Comment: Alright I'll keep reminding you, add me on fb as well, just search with my name. Also,  there is a reason, y we are using postMessage. That iframe is going to contain an external app(say a box like facebook like) that'll be used to add a task from Gmail, so I need the title name etc etc.. Thanks for the tip though, it'll help me in my other projects... :)

Comment: No, I don't, I was actually cloning the way it uses to add the button. Thats it. Need it for my company's plugin. Btw, you didn't send me any request on FB or Skype. Please do, coz I think I'll be needing more help if needed :)

Comment: Ah I don't have FB or Skype I use just email, SO, and sites like mozillazine, forums at mozilla, and google groups for mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

in the code you posted, im not seeing the toolbar button get added, its not even in the customize view, did you test your sample code you uploaded?

the addAsTask function is failing hard in your sample code because elements like #sample-button and #TasksPanel don't exist. please make sure your test case works before uploading

Comment: edit: i fixed it by changing in overlay.xul ```<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">``` to ```<toolbarpalette id="nav-bar">```, if you want people to help you, make it as easy as possible for them otherwise they won't help you.

Comment: The Button is actually shown as default firefox buttons(forward/back/refersh etc etc) in the customize toolbar icons, but when you drag them out to the toolbar, the actual button appears. This actually doesn't happen in my plugin, but its an issue the sample plugin i made for you. It doesn't actually install the button in the first go. Need to add a script for that also. Also, the button that will send use postMessage is in Gmail(Go to Gmail,in of your mails, there above in the buttons, you'll find Add a Sample Task, click on it - that is the button that callbacks addAsTask() func on click)

Comment: on opening panel there is no "add task" or "open page" button, just a refresh button. Seriously man if you want help, don't make the people that are helping you have to debug and recreate your addon to help you... You wont get help. I can't beleive @noit had the patience to help you... Excuse my frustration... I had 10 minutes to look into your problem but never could address it because of so much other crap in the way.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I was actually in a little hurry. I did test it out, like I said in the above comment, but didn't really fix everything, as I was too much concentrated on the main issue of the window.postMessage function. Sorry again. I hope you are able to debug it now.

Comment: Open one of Your Mails. Then only you'll see the Add a Sample Task Button. I am able to run it on my comp.

Comment: If you can, come on Skype, my username is prateek.kathal, I'll show you that its working here and what problem m really having it.

Answer (score 0):

box.com/s/hxn16axnxbwc151h92g

the addon doesnt work on install but i see a problem here:

`function postMessageToWindow(win, message) {
    try {
        window.top.postMessage(message, '*');
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
         return false;
    }
}`

on line3 it says `window.top.` use `win.top.` also i dont think u need to use `.top`. just use `win.postMessage`

also is postMessage a function in the iframe? because when i look theres no postMessage function in tasks.html

Comment: No, there is no postMessage there, do we need to have it there as well? Also, I have been trying different way to get this to work. If you see my question, then the `postMessageToWindow` function given there is correct and what you want, but somehow, its not working.

Comment: Try to Download it again, I have fixed the plugin and it should work now. Please help me fix this :(

Comment: i will absolutely help you out, will download and take a look a little later. i need your cooperation. thanks for fixing bugs in that, it will allow me to debug it

Comment: Thank you. I am looking forward to it. :)